# Function Passing If-Statement Using String?

Tags: c, string, function, strcmp

String initialization:

```
main(){
char monthName[20];
int days;

printf("Enter the month: ");
fgets(monthName, 20, stdin);

days = monthCalc(monthName);
}
```

Function:

```
int monthCalc(char monthName[20]) {
int days = 0;

if (strcmp(monthName, "January") == 0)
    days = 31;
else if (strcmp(monthName, "February") == 0)
    days = 28;
else if (strcmp(monthName, "March") == 0)
    days = 31;
else if (strcmp(monthName, "April") == 0)
    days = 30;
```

For Example, if I enter January, the char array does collect the string "January". But when compared using strcmp in the monthCalc function, days will not get 31 like it should. Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Is this in C? There isn't a language tagged to this question.

Comment: Remove the trailing `newline` because `fgets` retains it.

Comment: Is this all of your code? Because clearly you don't return anything from your `monthyCalc` function nor is there a closing brace.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's not a duplicate of this question, that's isn't the issue the OP has.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek it is not the same question, i.e. duplicate, but the answers duplicate what could be answered here. What is the issue if it is not this? Not an incomplete function - enough was given to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek please give a good reason why this question should be re-opened.

Comment: @WeatherVane *"enough was given to illustrate the problem"*, your assuming correct code. The OP might not even be returning `days` from the function, the question is off-topic for that reason until the OP provides working runnable code.

Comment: Oh for heaven's sake. It is quite clear what the problem is. If using `strcspn` does not solve it OP can ask again. For example "why does my function not return a value, I do not understand the compiler warning".

Comment: @JohnBillingham you say the input was correct, but if you print it like this `printf("<%s>", monthName);` that should expose the `newline` in the input string.